# Try UPSERT recursively increasing counter until success

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to replicate the behavior of Finder on a Mac.

- If I copy paste a file `example` in folder, where there is already a file with same name - it will create a file `example copy`.
- If I paste again, it will create `example copy 2`, and so on.
- If I delete `example copy`, and folder now has 2 files `example` and `example copy 2` and paste again, it will take unused name `example copy` again.

Assuming there is this table, is it possible to write an `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` that will try the name rules above until it succeeds?

```
CREATE TABLE public.files (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX files_name_index ON public.files USING btree (name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the name changes constantly, it is difficult to create a single `INSERT... ON CONFLICT` line that generates names dynamically with the behaviour you stated. A stored procedure, however, can be used to do this. A stored procedure that tries to insert a file name into the `files` table can be made in PostgreSQL. It can dynamically change the name in accordance with your requirements and retry the insertion if a unique constraint violation occurs. Names like `example copy`, `example copy 2`, and so forth can be produced by using a loop and handling exceptions. While using a bespoke method rather than a simple `INSERT... ON CONFLICT` allows for a more effective replication of the desired behaviour, it does so at the expense of performance.